# Pandas: interpret list of list datatypes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When reading delimited data from a file, the pandas library is able to interpret the types of the data columns.

When passing a pandas dataframe a list of lists of strings assembled through some process outside of pandas, pandas preserves the inner list types as strings:

```
data = [ ['1','2'],['3','4'] ]
cols = ['foo', 'biz']
df = DataFrame(columns=cols, data=data)
print(numpy.sum(df.values)) 

$: <literal sum of the strings>
```

Is there a way to trigger panda's type-interpretation logic on data generated within the running program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, that is a feature of the CSV parser pandas uses. You can enforce a single dtype using the `dtype` argument to the DataFrame constructor, or alternatively, as a post-processing step, you could do:

```
df.apply(lambda S: pd.to_numeric(S, errors='ignore'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, data=data, dtype=float)
```